# Windows Network Bridge

Tags: windows, networking

What does it means to create a network bridge in windows?

I have two network adapters, and having the option to create a bridge of the two. But what does it mean. if i plug both cables to my router, do i then have double the speed 2Gbit if its two 1gbit network adapters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would be NIC "bonding" or "teaming".

Bridging means to essentially create a software switch between the interfaces - so if you had one cable to your router and one cable to a different system, the other system would be able to communicate to the router via the bridging computer as if it were a network switch.